# Is it possible to set model name as configuration variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reflection, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm creating my own forum plug-in for Rails and I've met some problem with configuration file. I wanna make developer possible to select what model contain users infos so I wanna made example configuration file like:

```
# Example forumally configuration file
Forumally.config do |config|
  # ==> Formatter Configuration
  # Set default formatter to +ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper#simple_format+
  # which provide some simple formatting like wrapping with paragraphs and add
  # line breaks
  config.text_formatter = lambda {|text| simple_format text}

  # ==> User model configuration
  # Set user model name default is +User+
  config.user_model = User
end
```

Is it possible to set `user_model` variable to alias `User` model (or any other model that contain user info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to set user_model variable to alias User model (or any other model that contain user info).

Yes. That should work just fine.